# AWS Ealstic Beanstalk : Terminating HTTPS on EC2 Instances Running PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to allow https connections on my single instance EBS enviornment.

I followed steps from below link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-php.html

but after following these steps and deploying package, my instance health changed to **Degraded**

When I checked the cause I found a message there

> Following services are not running: proxy.

here is the screenshot

[image]

if anyone has idea then please let me know how to resolve this problem and make my instance running with https

Answer (score 1):

Check in your `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh`. Note that `01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh` might have a different name for you.

In there you need to change your proxy check if you're not using `apache/httpd` to `nginx`, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy nginx
```

If you are using `apache/httpd`, it means that there's something wrong with your apache runtime instance or process. Make sure the pid file is where is should be for the health check.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and the following post script solved the health warnings.

`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe

chmod 0755 /var/run/httpd
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy httpd
```