# AWS elasticbeanstalk: nginx server instead of apache (Health degraed)

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, nginx

My elasticbeanstalk application configuration

> 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.2 running PHP 7.0

I've replaced Apache server with Nginx and completely removed the `httpd` components.
Nginx works fine with out any problem however my application health is degraded.

Here is the error message

> Following services are not running: proxy

I've refered this question [AWS Ealstic Beanstalk : Terminating HTTPS on EC2 Instances Running PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653130/aws-ealstic-beanstalk-terminating-https-on-ec2-instances-running-php) and replace `01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh` content with this code

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy nginx
```

But it doesn't worked.

**Error log**

### /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log

> ------------------------------------- /var/log/httpd/error_log
>   ------------------------------------- [Mon Mar 13 11:35:04.118247 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 2063] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled
>   (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec) [Mon Mar 13 11:35:04.165984 2017]
>   [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2063] AH01757: generating secret for digest
>   authentication ... [Mon Mar 13 11:35:04.167309 2017]
>   [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2063] AH02282: No slotmem from
>   mod_heartmonitor [Mon Mar 13 11:35:04.611535 2017]
>   [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2063] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon)
>   configured -- resuming normal operations [Mon Mar 13 11:35:04.611612
>   2017] [core:notice] [pid 2063] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd
>   -D FOREGROUND' [Mon Mar 13 11:43:54.307049 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2063] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down